# Scraping a site code with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I wrote a code to get the code of a particular website, is there any way I can make it short or say less than 2kb.

If you have another code shorter than this ....i need it .☺
I have read and seen all other questions but they couldn't satisfy the problem.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import colored
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
import time
import replit
replit.clear()
print(colored("Welcome to the", "magenta"), colored("CyanCoding", "cyan"), 
colored("web crawler.", "magenta"))
time.sleep(2)
print()
print(colored("You can easily find websites and their code with this powerful 
tool.", "magenta"))
time.sleep(4)
print()
website = input(colored("Please enter your website (do NOT include http:// or 
https://) >", "yellow"))
print()
if "http://" not in website:
    website = ''.join(("http://", website))
print(colored("We're scraping %s. If this takes longer than 15 seconds, the                 
website failed to connect." % (website), "magenta"))
time.sleep(2)
try:
    page = requests.get(website)
except ConnectionError:
    print()
    print(colored("The website you entered does not exist.", "red"))
else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find('title')
    print()
    print(colored("The title of %s is %s." % (website, title.text), "cyan"))
    time.sleep(4)
    print()
    setContinue = input(colored("Would you like to scrape the rest of this     
page?", "yellow")).lower()
    if setContinue == "yes" or setContinue == "y" or setContinue == "yea" or     
    setContinue == "yeah" or setContinue == "sure" or setContinue == "o yea"     
    or setContinue == "I thought that's what I was doing bro":
        print()
        print(colored("Creating your scraped page...", "magenta"))
        time.sleep(5)
        print()
        replit.clear()
        print(colored(soup, "cyan"))`
```

Comment: Your code *is* less than 2Kb, so you are basically done then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 possible improvements:

1. I see that you are repeating the following sequence: print a string with a color, sleep a certain amount of time, and print an empty line (except the third time). You can factorize that by defining a function:

   `print_delayed(string_to_print, color, time_to_sleep, print_empty_line=True)`

   If `print_empty_line` is set to `False`, then the `print()` action is not called
2. Then, at some point, you examine quite a lot of possibilities for the `setContinue` input, resulting in too many ORs. Wouldn't it be better to declare a `list` containing all these possible values (let's call it  `allowed_inputs`) and then just change the condition to `if setContinue in allowed_inputs` ?
3. if your website's url does not contain 'http://', you do `website = ''.join(("http://", website))`. ie declaring a tuple and calling one of its methods. By doing so, you use too much memory footprint, wouldn't it be simpler just to do `website = 'http://%s' % (website,)` ?

A warning to conclude : the last possible value for `setContinue` (`"I thought that's what I was doing bro"`) contains upper case letters, but your variable is supposed to be all-lowercase, by the way you declared it. You might miss that possible value because of this mistake.